# Flask App that uses another standalone app?

Tags: python, flask

I have a Flask app structured as:

```
/app
    /app
    /anotherAppIncludedInsideApp
/flask
/virtualenv
/run.py
```

Think of `app` like a webpage with a news feed section `anotherAppIncludedInsideApp` that is it's own separate app.

My question is how should I approach this?

Comment: There are a lot of approaches you could take.  Regrettably, there are too many approaches, leading this to being "too broad".

Comment: @Makoto Could you give me the approach you think is most accepted in the community?

Comment: Not really, since there are so many ways to approach this problem.  Besides, I wouldn't know off-hand anyway; I know Python, but Flask isn't one of those things I've got in my mastery toolkit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Makoto that it's a very broad question. You might want to create a blueprint -- see the Flask documentation: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/blueprints/

Comment: Seems quite a bit of an overkill, but I'll research more into it.